# C++ Pass a string into a pipe to gnuplot

Tags: c++, string, pipe, gnuplot

I'm having a small problem passing a string to gnuplot from c++ I can pass integers easily enough, but when I try a string (user defined as "title" earlier in the code):

```
fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "set title %s\n", title);
```

I get the error:

```
error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type ‘std::string {aka class std::basic_string<char>}’ through ‘...’
```

So instead I tried using:

```
fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "set title %s\n", title.c_str());
```

and the code actually compiled, but when I ran it I got the error from Gnuplot:

```
line 0: undefined variable: h
```

Where "h" is just the test sting defined by "title".

Does anyone have any ideas on how to pass this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you quote the string for Gnuplot, ie `fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "set title '%s'\n", title);`?  I'm not posting this as an answer because since you didn't provide a complete example, I couldn't try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the title in quotes:

```
fprintf(gnuplotPipe, "set title \"%s\"\n", title.c_str());
```

Comment: Ah so my problem was just simple syntax... It works perfectly now, thank you so much!!